# Tkinter Exe (created using pyinstaller) starts creating multiple windows

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing, pyinstaller

I am using python 3.6. I have created a simple tkinter application in which i pass 3 integers to a pool (multiprocessing.pool) and when i press the button "Start process". it displays the resultant list in tkinter window. My code is given below:

```
import tkinter as tk
import multiprocessing as mp
from tkinter import Label,IntVar

def worker_function(x):
    result = 42*x
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("300x300")
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Start Process", command=lambda: var.set(1))
    button.pack()
    aa = Label(root, text="Empty String", font=('arial', 15, 'bold'))
    aa.pack()
    pool = mp.Pool(3)
    var = IntVar(master=root)
    button.wait_variable(var)
    values = list(pool.map(worker_function, [1, 2, 3]))
    aa.config(text=str(values))
    root.update()
    root.mainloop()
    pool.close()
```

[image]

When i run my code, it is executed with no error.
However after creating my exe using pyinstaller and run it, it keeps creating copy of tk window.

I am pretty sure it is due to using multiprocessing
but I don't know how to resolve it. I am sure someone here knows
what I am doing wrong.

Comment: start with putting `mp.freeze_support()` right after `if __name__ == "__main__":`